# Django Filter Queries Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling getting the right query for my project. Here is an example or my model :

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    certification_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="43534")
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=True, null=True)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    rate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
    signer = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    item_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
    certification_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)        
    packing_list = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y-%m-%d', blank=True, null=True)
    wholesale = models.BooleanField(default=False)       
    auth_fee = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, blank=True, null=True)
    label_position = models.CharField(max_length=250)    
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', blank=True, null=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item

    def total_auth_fee(self):
            return self.quantity * self.auth_fee

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=30,blank=False)
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)  
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Client"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

How do I get phone_number, (name of the client and email address also) is in inbuilt django forms? Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear, which model do you want to query? What does a query has to do with a form? Where's your form?

Comment: i want to query the client model

Comment: Then what query have you tried and doesn't work?

Comment: fifth_result = Client.objects.filter(Q(phone_number=q))

Comment: OK, stackoverflow is no place for interactive exercise, so you should give as detailed information as possible, so I suggest you adding whatever you have tried in your question when you ask. As of your query, I'm not sure what are you trying to do, because `Client` model doesn't even have a field called `project`.

Comment: Unclear question, ```Client.objects.filter(phone_number=q)``` will get you client objects, and name and email of the client are in the user model. ```user.get_full_name()``` and ```user.email```.

Answer (score 0):

in you HTML code you can access User information easily. for example

```
<p>{{ user.username }}</p>
<p>{{ user.email }}</p>
<p>{{ user.first_name }}</p>
<p>{{ user.last_name }}</p>
```

and if you want to access them in a Django form, just add `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` first of your code

for example look at this code. it's a simple form for add a new user

**views.py**

```
def Signup(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            new_password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            new_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            new_first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            new_last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            #hashed_password = hashlib.md5(new_password).hexdigest()
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(
                        username = new_username, 
                        email = new_email,
                        first_name = new_first_name,
                        last_name = new_last_name)
            if new_password:
                new_user.set_password(new_password)
            else:
                new_user.set_unusable_password()
            new_user.save()
            new_user.is_active = True
            auth_user = authenticate(username = new_username, password = new_password)
            if auth_user is not None:
                login(request, auth_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'Dashboard/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class SignupForm1(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name' , 'last_name')
```

if you look at `forms.py` the `SignupForm1` inherit from `User` then you can have the user information ( fields )